# Select date on change Xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

IM trying to display a calendar in a dialog and let user select the date. i was able to get the current date dislayed but having difficulty in selecting a date when its changed. Can anyone please help me figure this? im posting the code i have below

```
namespace PlayProject
{
    [Activity(Label = "GChartActivity")]
    public class GChartActivity : Activity, CalendarView.IOnDateChangeListener
    {

        private EditText fieldTaskDate;
        private string taskDate;
        private CalendarView cal;
        private SimpleDateFormat sdf;
        private long taskDateLong;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Create your application here
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.GoogleChart);
            cal = FindViewById<CalendarView>(Resource.Id.calendarView);
            fieldTaskDate = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText_TaskDate);
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");



            Button b = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button_Cal);
            b.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs args)
            {
                AlertDialog calDialog = DateDialogBox();
                calDialog.Show();

                Calendar date = Calendar.Instance;
                string currDate = sdf.Format(date.Time);
                calDialog.SetTitle(currDate);
                taskDate = currDate;
                taskDateLong = date.TimeInMillis;
                Button yesBtn = calDialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Positive);
                Button noBtn = calDialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative);
                //yesBtn.Click += (s, e) =>
                //{
                //    GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                //    gCal.Add(CalendarField.Date, -1);
                //    long lMillis = gCal.Time.Time;

                //    fieldTaskDate.Text = taskDate;
                //    calDialog.Dismiss();
                //};
                noBtn.Click += (s, e) => calDialog.Dismiss();
                cal.SetOnDateChangeListener(this);
            };
        }       
        private AlertDialog DateDialogBox()
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = this.LayoutInflater;
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CalendarDialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder dateDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dateDialogBuilder.SetTitle("Date");
            dateDialogBuilder.SetView(view);

            dateDialogBuilder.SetPositiveButton("SetDate", (s, e) =>
            {
                GregorianCalendar gCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                gCal.Add(CalendarField.Date, -1);
                long lMillis = gCal.Time.Time;

                fieldTaskDate.Text = taskDate;

            });
            dateDialogBuilder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (s, e) =>
            {

            });

            AlertDialog dialog = dateDialogBuilder.Create();

            return dialog;
        }


        public void OnSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            string curdate = sdf.Format(cal.Date);

            taskDate = curdate;
            taskDateLong = cal.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into "DatePickerDialog" this does exactly what you are trying to do. Here is an example. http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/date_picker/

Comment: Im aware of that control, but i want to display a calendar to let user select a date.

Comment: The actual picker might vary depending on Android Version, if thats what you are asking. If you want the UI to be same across all that, then you might consider creating a custom View Dialog. Personally I would say, let the OS handle it for you.